# Every time I try to run a newly installed app from the Ubuntu Software app the icon blinks in the task bar for a while then disappears

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I have had this problem with Spotify, Instagraph and a couple other apps. When I install an app from Ubuntu Software everything works as it should until I try to run the newly installed app. I click the icon in the start menu and the icon flashes as they do when they are loading for about 20 seconds then it disappears as if it closed itself before it could start.

Anyone got any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: you can try to run the program from the command line, and post your error output, that would help us start to diagnose the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a simple update fixed the problem because I hadn't ran an update for quite some time.

I ran these commands in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Some apps I had to delete then reinstall after the update then they worked fine.